# External Id attribute of an Account field

Tags: custom-field, account, externalid

When populating a custom field in Account, is a text field marked as External ID so different from a different text custom field in Account NOT marked as External ID, that I would be getting an error from a 3rd party tool that's trying to populate a text value in that field and gives me an error that the value is of the wrong type?

I've used all my External ID options on the Account object, but this is the only difference I can see between a field I have from a managed package and a custom field that I'm trying to replicate.

Exact error I'm getting:

```
Account ID: id value of incorrect type: KC-OLD-8000012B
```

The value in the field from the managed package would have a value formatted like this:

```
KC-8000034A
```

Comment: Afraid your question is a little confusing and hard to follow / understand

Comment: It sounds like it is trying to populate the Id field instead of an external ID field. Are you sure the field mapping is correct?

Comment: You're right @Daniel, I was looking at this all wrong.  The error had to do with the mapping of the Account ID field, not the custom field I was referring to in my question that is **PART** of the mapping to get this Account ID value.  This morning I was able to find an old mapping that had worked previously.  I don't understand how it works because it's referring to a non-existing custom field on Opportunity, but it works.   Thanks for taking a shot at it Daniel and pointing me in the right direction.